# When there is no rule for a style, what happens

Tags: css

When I use a style and that style is not defined because the media query that defines it is false and that media query is the only place that style is defined what happens when the browser renders a page that uses the style?

Comment: The browser will just render the element with default settings if nothing else has done some styling on it.

Answer (score 1):

Every bowser has sets of default styles, called user agent styles, that it uses to render elements. For example, WebKit is the rendering engine used by Chrome and Safari.

If you do not assign a style to an element, the browser will use its default.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say `assign a style` you mean `class="..."` or style="..."`? If a style is undefined, you are also saying the browser will use the default?

Comment: Both, and yes. CSS classes (which are assigned via the HTML class attribute) are just groupings of individual styles.